# Why isn't there a maven extensionManagement element for extensions?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

We use an extension in our projects and until now put the extension under the pluginManagement section of the maven parent pom:

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.extensions</groupId>
         <artifactId>beer-maven-lifecycle</artifactId>
         <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

But this results in the following warning:

> [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.extensions:beer-maven-lifecycle: Failed to parse
>   plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.extensions:beer-maven-lifecycle
>   (/somerepo/org.apache.maven.extensions-0.0.0.jar): No plugin
>   descriptor found at META-INF/maven/plugin.xml
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginDescriptorParsingException: Failed to
>   parse plugin descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.extensions:beer-maven-lifecycle
>   (/somerepo/org.apache.maven.extensions-0.0.0.jar): No plugin
>   descriptor found at META-INF/maven/plugin.xml

Which makes sense since it is an extension and not a plugin. But there is no extensionManagement element. So what would be a way to handle this? E.g. this project also describes the [issue](https://github.com/opendaylight/odlparent/blob/master/odlparent-lite/pom.xml) (lines 78-80)...